# How to append values as a new column to existing text file using python

Tags: python, for-loop, glob

I tried to append values to a file. First I unpack values from i, j from frozen set and then I append those values to a file. Again I need to append x values in another column  rather than at the end of file. Kindly help me in this regard.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from molmod import *
from molmod.bonds import bonds

import glob

for file in glob.glob("*.xyz"):

  mol = Molecule.from_file(file)
  mol.graph = MolecularGraph.from_geometry()
   
  bos = list(mol.graph.edges)
  
  for edge in bos:
    i, j = edge
    print(i, j, file = open(file.replace('xyz', 'txt'), 'a'))
    s = list(mol.graph.orders)
    for x in s:
           print(x, file = open(file.replace('xyz', 'txt'), 'a'))
```

Output file:

```
4 5
1 2
2 3
1 4
4 6
6 7
0 1
8 9
8 10
10 11
11 13
13 15
16 15
16 17
8 6
10 2
11 12
13 14
18 19
18 20
25 20
25 27
16 18
27 15
21 22
21 23
24 21
20 21
25 26
27 28
1.0
2.0
1.0
2.0
2.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
2.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
2.0
```

Desired Output :

```
4 5        1.0 
1 2        2.0
2 3        1.0
1 4        2.0
4 6        2.0
6 7        1.0
0 1        1.0
8 9        1.0
8 10       2.0
10 11      1.0
11 13      1.0
13 15      1.0
16 15      2.0
16 17      1.0
8 6        2.0
10 2       2.0
11 12      1.0
13 14      1.0
18 19      2.0
18 20      1.0
25 20      1.0
25 27      1.0
16 18      1.0
27 15      2.0
21 22      1.0
21 23      1.0
24 21      1.0
20 21      1.0
25 26      2.0
27 28      1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create 3 columns in one pass, so there is no need to "append" anything. It is like:

```
bos = list(mol.graph.edges)
s = list(mol.graph.orders)
f = open(file.replace('xyz', 'txt'), 'a')
for i in range(len(bos)):
    i, j = bos[i]
    print(i, j, s[i], file = f)
```

If you want to append another column to the file created above, you need to read the lines from the file, append the text to each line, and write them back to the file.

```
myNewData = [1, 2, 999, 444] #new data to append to an existing file

f = open(file.replace('xyz', 'txt'), 'r+')   #open an existing file
allLines = f.read().split("\n")    #read all lines from the file
f.seek(0)  #rewind the file pointer to start writing from the first line
for i in range(min(len(allLines), len(myNewData))):
    print(allLines[i], myNewData[i], file = f)   #append new data to each line
f.close()   #done
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Could you please tell me if I want to append, how can I do it. Because I need to generate another data and I need to put that data in the same file as column. If I use append, can I use it for new data also. If possible please help me.

Comment: I have just modified the answer to include code to append a column to an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append some value at the end of a line then, just do that.

```py
with open(filename, "w") as f:  # open in write mode
  for x in s:
     x = str(x) + your_value + "\n"  # assuming x can be converted to string
     f.write(x)
```

Hope that helps.